# Git through SSH proxy works in Windows but not in Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

**Common scenario**: I am trying to access a git server in our company network. I can't access it directly, but I can ssh connect to my PC within the company network and from there connect to the git server.

I have set up the following ssh config:

```
Host company.pc
    HostName public.company.pc
    User user
    Port 1234
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host gitserver
    HostName private.company.gitsrv
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitserver
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    ProxyCommand ssh company.pc exec nc %h %p
```

Then I issue the command `git clone git@gitserver:path/to/git`

On Windows this works with no problem: I am first prompted for password to company.pc, then prompted password for `~/.ssh/gitserver` and the repository clones.

On Ubuntu, however, after I input the first two passwords I am prompted once more for git@gitserver. My guess is that in Ubuntu the `~/.ssh/gitserver` private key is not used to authenticate to gitserver.

Comment: Try `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p company.pc`. It's not an answer about password/key, just a better `ProxyCommand` for newer versions of OpenSSH.

Comment: @phd what is the advantage of the newer command? How is it different?

Comment: Builtin to OpenSSH, no need to run external program `nc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Somehow I managed to download wrong `gitserver` key to the Ubuntu machine.